# Python array slice not working as expected

Tags: python, arrays, slice

I'm trying to write a program for a given array and a value, to remove all instances of that value in place and return the new length.

Example:
Given input array nums = [3,2,2,3], val = 3

It should return length = 2, with the first two elements of nums being 2.

Here is my code:

**Code 1:**

```
def removeElement(self, nums, val):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :type val: int
    :rtype: int
    """
    i = 0
    j = len(nums) - 1

    while i <= j:
        while i <= j and nums[j] != val:
            j -= 1

        while i <= j and nums[i] == val:
            i += 1

        if i <= j:
            nums[i], nums[j] = nums[j], nums[i]

    return len(nums[i:])
```

This returns the array slice in reverse order.

```
Input:
[3,2,2,3]
3 
Output: [3,3] 
Expected: [2,2]
```

However, if I make slight modifications at the end of the code 1, it gives me the correct output:

```
    nums[:] = nums[i:]
    return len(nums[i:])
```

**Code 2:**

```
def removeElement(self, nums, val):
    """
    :type nums: List[int]
    :type val: int
    :rtype: int
    """
    i = 0
    j = len(nums) - 1

    while i <= j:
        while i <= j and nums[j] != val:
            j -= 1

        while i <= j and nums[i] == val:
            i += 1

        if i <= j:
            nums[i], nums[j] = nums[j], nums[i]

    nums[:] = nums[i:]
    return len(nums)
```

I cant figure out why my code 1 doesnt work. Could someone help me understand why slice doesnt work as expected?

Comment: I don't think either approach works, unless you have some restriction on the input that you haven't mentioned.

Comment: The strange thing is that I ran your code1 and it worked as expected, i.e. with input [3,2,2,3] returns [2,2] and length 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would do what you intend ("... remove all instances of that value in place and return the new length"):

```
def remove_element(nums, val):
    nums[:] = [x for x in nums if x != val]
    return len(nums)
```

Test:

```
nums = [3, 2, 2, 3]
val = 3
print(remove_element(nums, val))
print(nums)
```

Output:

```
2
[2, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first example works.

When you slice a new list is created. So in your first code sample you are creating a new list at the end containing the *correct* result, but never returning it.

In your second code example you are assigning the newly created list to the original list and are hence able to access the final result.